# API Gateway - Return XML or JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway

I have a node API Gateway stack and a Node Lambda. I've been trying to get API gateway to return content-type: application/xml OR application/json depending on the request (returnType=xml or returnType=json).

I have tried adding response models and that didn't work. BinaryTypes didn't work either. I have gotten it to do either application/json OR application/xml but I can't get it to do both. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? or should I create two separate endpoints?

This example always returns application/json.

Here is my lambda:

```js
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    var format = event.format;

    if (!format) {
        callback(Error("[BadRequest] missing parameters"));
    }

    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        https
            .get("exampleendpoint.com", (res) => {
                let body = "";

                res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                    body += chunk;
                });

                res.on("end", () => {
                    var results = JSON.parse(body);
                    if (format && format.toUpperCase() === "XML") {
                        var response = {
                            statusCode: 200,
                            headers: {
                                "content-type": "application/xml"
                            },
                            body: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><result>' +
                                OBJtoXML(results) +
                                "</result>",
                        };
                        resolve(response);
                    } else {
                        var response = {
                            statusCode: 200,
                            headers: {
                                "content-type": "application/json"
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify(results),
                        };
                        resolve(response);
                    }
                });
            })
            .on("error", (e) => {
                var response = {
                    statusCode: 500,
                    body: "",
                    errorMessage: "Error from example.com",
                };
                resolve(response);
            });
    });
    return promise;
};
```

Here is my api gateway code:

```js
const epqApi = new gateway.RestApi(this, "restApi", {
    restApiName: "resultsApi",
    cloudWatchRole: true,
    description: "Calls the service for the app",
    endpointTypes: [gateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL],
    deployOptions: {
        stageName: "prod",
        loggingLevel: gateway.MethodLoggingLevel.OFF,
        dataTraceEnabled: false,
    },
});

const epqResource = epqApi.root.addResource("v1");

const epqIntegration: gateway.LambdaIntegration =
    new gateway.LambdaIntegration(generatePqsResultFunction, {
        proxy: false,
        allowTestInvoke: true,
        passthroughBehavior: gateway.PassthroughBehavior.NEVER,
        contentHandling: gateway.ContentHandling.CONVERT_TO_TEXT,
        requestTemplates: {
            "application/json": `{ 
                "format":"$input.params(\'format\')"     
            }`,
        },
        integrationResponses: [{
                statusCode: "200",
                responseParameters: {
                    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'",
                },
                responseTemplates: {
                    "application/json": "$input.path('$.body')",
                    "application/xml": "$input.path('$.body')",
                },
            },
            {
                statusCode: "400",
                selectionPattern: "^\\[BadRequest\\].*",
                responseParameters: {
                    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'",
                },
                responseTemplates: {
                    "application/javascript": "#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')) {\"errorMessage\" : \"$input.path('$.errorMessage')\"}",
                },
            },
        ],
    });

epqResource.addMethod("GET", epqIntegration, {
    requestParameters: {
        //all params need to be in here, even if they are not required
        "method.request.querystring.x": false,
        "method.request.querystring.y": false,
        "method.request.querystring.units": false,
        "method.request.querystring.format": false,
        "method.request.querystring.wkid": false,
        "method.request.querystring.includeDate": false,
    },
    methodResponses: [
        // Successful response from the integration
        {
            statusCode: "200",
            responseParameters: {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
            },
        },
        {
            statusCode: "400",
            responseParameters: {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
            },
        },
    ],
});
}
```